# Is it possible to use Mvc3 razor scripts aspx page view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webforms-view-engine

Is it possible to use Mvc3 razor scripts inside mvc 2 aspx page view and mvc 2 ascx control view?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are asking. What do you mean by "razor scripts"? Do you mean a razor partial? In that case, then yes. An aspx view can call a razor partial just fine (and vice versa).

If you mean embed a chunk of razor inside of an aspx/ascx, then no.

Razor is intended for MVC 3, but people have successfully gotten it working in MVC 2. Such as this question: [How to Download Razor View Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644698/how-to-download-razor-view-engine/4652007)

Comment: It was a ASP.NET MVC 2 application but i converted now that to ASP.NET MVC 3 application. But now i have Views which are .aspx and .ascx. Now how to use Razor scripts (ex: @Name) inside these .aspx and .ascx controls. I am aware these scripts are possible inside .cshtml and .vbhtml files.

Comment: That isn't possible. You will need to convert the aspx views to razor views if you want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In short No. You can use Razor and the WebForms view engines alongside each other, but you cannot mix them in the same view.

Besides, as far as I know, you can't use Razor with ASP.NET MVC 2 either although I'm not 100% sure on that last one.

Comment: It was a ASP.NET MVC 2 application but i converted now that to ASP.NET MVC 3 application. But now i have Views which are .aspx and .ascx. Now how to use Razor scripts (ex: @Name) inside these .aspx and .ascx controls. I am aware these scripts are possible inside .cshtml and .vbhtml files.

Comment: @alagesan - You can't use Razor notation (@Name, etc) inside an aspx/ascx file. As Matt says, you can have a .cshtml Partial view (with razor notation) and call it from an ascx, but you can't use Razor in an aspx view just like you can't use C# in a .vb file.